# IIS Web.Config Redirects

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-7.5

I'm trying to see if there is a way to put all of my redirects inside of it and then reference it inside my main web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="index">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://mynewurl.com" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: To be a bit more specific, I'm using location tags for my url changes.

Comment: What kind of "web.config" redirects? Please provide examples so as to be really specific.

Comment: Hi Lex.  I just updated my original post with the example code.